# How to convert day and compare this with first day of month?

Tags: c#, datetime

EDITED: (sorry, English is not my main language, and I sincerely apologize to all people who read this question.)

I edited my question to explain my problem. Sorry about that.

I want to compare two days. When I add data to it and save the day in one file `time_was_send.txt`.

Then it should compare with the first day of the current month. If it is true true, it will execute method `SendMail.sendDailyMail`.

I'm having problems with getfirstdayoflastmonth() method it always subtracts 1 month while I want it to take the first day of the current month.

I just want to compare if they be the same day and month or not - the year is not important.

So I want to compare something like this.
`26/12` - read from file `time_was_send.txt` vs `getfirstdayoflastmonth(currentDay)` while `currentDay = 1/12`.

To help you to understand, here is my code,

```
string path = "C:\\time_was_send.txt";
string timeFromFile = ReadFromFile(path);
DateTime m_timeFromFile = DateTime.ParseExact(timeFromFile, "dd-MM-yyyy", null);
string s = now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
DateTime timeNow = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "dd-MM-yyyy", null);

if (m_timeFromFile == procedureMethod.getfirstdayoflastmonth(timeNow))
{
    try
    {
        SendMail.sendDailyMail(listXML);
    }
    catch{}
}
```

Here is getfirstdayoflastmonth() method:

```
public static DateTime getfirstdayoflastmonth(DateTime time)
{
    return new DateTime(time.AddMonths(-1).Year, time.AddMonths(-1).Month, 1);
}
```

Update 1:
I resolved my problem.
In `if()` statement, I add `.Day` and `.Month` to compare.
It works. Thanks to all people who helped me.

```
if (m_timeFromFile.Day == procedureMethod.getfirstdayoflastmonth(timeNow).Day && m_timeFromFile.Month == procedureMethod.getfirstdayoflastmonth(timeNow).Month)
{
    try
    {
        SendMail.sendDailyMail(listXML);
    }
    catch{}
}
```

I edited `AddMonths(-1)` to `AddMonths(0)`.

```
public static DateTime getfirstdayoflastmonth(DateTime time)
{
    return new DateTime(time.AddMonths(-1).Year, time.AddMonths(0).Month, 1);
}
```

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are asking or what the problem is. Do you want code that will only send the email when it is the first day of the month?

Comment: So, I'm not the only one who didn't understand anything!

Comment: Sorry, I was edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the first day of the month, you could make use of `DateTime` `class` methods and properties **alone**.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now; //change this to any date you want
DateTime firstDayOfMonth = dt.AddDays(1-dt.Day); //the trick is here, minus the DatetTime by the current day (of month) + 1, you necessarily get the first day of the month
DayOfWeek dow = firstDayOfMonth.DayOfWeek; //this is the first day of the month (this month's first day is Tuesday)
```

If you need first day of month, use `firstDayOfMonth`. If you need the day of week on the day, use `dow`. If you want to compare the `firstDayOfMonth` with some other `DateTime` but only interested in comparing the date, simply do:

```
firstDayOfMonth.Date == someOtherDays.Date
```

And if you need to use the time too, you could check `TimeOfDay`.

Basically, try to find out more about the `DateTime` class methods and properties. The class is **really** handy to use for such task as yours!

Edit: to compare both day and month (but not year), use `DateTime.Day` and `DateTime.Month` properties

Comment: I using DateTime.Day but it can't getDay() to compare.

Comment: DateTime.Day is to check the day of the month. So 21-Jan-2013 and 21-Feb-2020 will return the same result (that is 21). You shouldn't do this. What you probably want is DateTime.Date (see example in the answer). If you want to find the first day of last month, you could use AddMonths(-1) from the firstDayOfMonth above. Then, only if you need, to find the DayOfWeek (that is, Monday, Tuesday, etc) of the last month, you can use the result and get its .DayOfWeek property.

Comment: If you also need the month to be the same, and not only the day, then you should give two statements: if (firstDayOfMonth.Day == otherDateTime.Day && firstDayOfMonth.Month == otherDateTime.Month) { //do something }

Comment: Thanks @lan, I resolved my problem and I update in my question. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Ok, I can see that you use two comparisons there. Great! ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;

DateTime firstDayOfMonth = new DateTime(dateTime.Year,dateTime.Month,1);

if (firstDayOfMonth.DayOfWeek.Equals(dateTime.DayOfWeek))

    MessageBox.Show("The day is matching with first day of the month" + dateTime.DayOfWeek);
```

Something like this would help you.